# Is there any especial name for this identity in set theory? $A'=B \to B'=A$ Can we call it symmetry property for the complement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there any especial name for this identity in set theory? $A'=B \to B'=A$.
$A$ and $B$ are two sets and $A'$ is the complement of $A$.
Can we call it symmetry property of the complement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This property is called *involution*, or the *involutive property* of the complement.

In general, a unary operation $(-)^*$ is an involution if $x^{**} = x$ for all $x$. Note that this is equivalent to saying $a^* = b \Rightarrow b^* =a$ for all $a,b$.